What is this bootloader warning?
In my HTC One A9, when I boot in download mode, at the bottom there is the warning:
If you flash a ROM that is not from HTC it could lead to.... (security issues)
Does it mean it has a custom ROM?. At the upper side it says ** locked **
Also is there a way to know if bootloader has been re-locked?

A [re-]locked bootloader requires a signed firmware otherwise it wouldn't boot. The only devices where you can detect a re-locked bootloader are those that contain a security fuse (hardware or software). The only devices I know that have such a fuse are Samsung Knox devices.

@Robert So if the OS successfully [Can boot] and the bootloader is [Locked], it means the phone is in its factory defaults, is that correct?

On a recent Android phone I would say yes, but on Android 6 I don't know. I am not sure if verified boot/vb meta already exists which allows to verify the whole system partition for authenticity and integrity. This technique is common (mandatory?) on recent devices but on your old thing?

What I miss in all your questions is a why. What do you want to do that you buy an totally outdated and insecure system and then care about if it is manipulated? That doesn't fit together. If you would really care for security than you wouldn't buy such a phone or only with the plan to replace the whole firmware with something self compiled.


If you flash a ROM that is not from HTC it could lead to.... (security issues)
Does it mean it has a custom ROM?

Probably not. It's most likely a warning that if you use ROMs that aren't from HTC, you're responsible for whatever happens, and HTC won't (and can't) help you if you encounter problems. Flashing Android devices that you rely on does involve some risk. You can't complain if manufacturers warn you about that.
